# GridView - select first row doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have wird problem with gridview and select checkbox for one row.

[image]

I get correct Text in Label, but if i select checkbox from first row:

[image]

I get: Room not pick

BUTTON CLICK

protected void bookButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {


            var chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox) row.FindControl("checkboxID");
            int id_room = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                Label1.Text = id_room.ToString();

                /* 
                String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
                 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                 {
                        //STORED PROCEDURE CALL
                 }

            }

            else
            {

                Label1.Text ="Room not pick";
            }
                */
        }
    }
```

AND GRIDVIEW

```
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table border-0 table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" BorderWidth="0px">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Number" HeaderText="Number" SortExpression="Number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Picture" HeaderText="Picture" SortExpression="Picture" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="ID"  HeaderText="IDP" SortExpression="ID" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <input type="checkbox" CssClass="custom-checkbox" ID="checkboxID" runat="server"  />
                        </ItemTemplate>

                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: show me you selected event or checkbox checked event

Comment: @ArunPratap I don't have. I check if chechbox is selected here:
var chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox) row.FindControl("checkboxID");
int id_room = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
            if (chk.Checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index is wrong. Its the 4 column. As its a zero based index, you should use 3

```
int id_room = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text);
```

A cleaner way will be to use `ItemTemplate`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IDP" SortExpression="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="roomID" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And access it like

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
    var chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxID");
    var selectedRoomID = (Label)row.FindControl("roomID");
    if (chk.Checked) {
        Label1.Text = selectedRoomID.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: In gridview I have 5 columns: ROOMNUMBER | PICTURE | PRICE | CHECKBOX | ID_ROOM, so ID_ROOM is 4. column I think or not?

Comment: The checkbox comes after room_id. so checkbox is the 5th column and room_id is the 4th. So the zero based index will be 3

Comment: I change row.Cells[4].Text to row.Cells[3].Text  and not change other code. It's still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks @naveen! I change the code like this:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            var chk = (HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("checkboxID");
            var selectedRoomID = (Label)row.FindControl("Label2");

            if (chk.Checked && chk != null)
            {

                Label1.Text = selectedRoomID.Text;
            }
            else
               {
              Label1.Text = "error";
                }
```

and change ID_ROOM col to ItemTemplates.